# Loading dataframe from url on hackerrank

Tags: python, pandas

Doing a hackerrank problem and can't figure out why I can't load a dataframe from the URL given

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests
import urllib

url = "https://hrcdn.net/restoflink.csv"


df = pd.read_csv(url2)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1346, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1253, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1299, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1248, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1008, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 948, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1415, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 919, in connect
    self.sock = self._create_connection(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 822, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 953, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/submission/20230103/11/53/hackerrank-725270a2c246ce29a6de7a3dd77fab59/code/Solution.py", line 10, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 610, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 462, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 819, in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1050, in _make_engine
    return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1867, in __init__
    self._open_handles(src, kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1362, in _open_handles
    self.handles = get_handle(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 558, in get_handle
    ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 289, in _get_filepath_or_buffer
    req = urlopen(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 195, in urlopen
    return urllib.request.urlopen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 517, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 534, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1389, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1349, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

I have tried using the requests module to load the csv then using pd.read_csv() but I got another error then

Comment: your error is independent of pandas: *Temporary failure in name resolution*, this is a DNS issue

Comment: Final line of code should say 'df = pd.read_csv(url)'

Comment: Even ignoring that, I get a 404 error

Comment: Thanks, how do I go about solving a DNS issue?

Comment: Re 404: I replaced the link with restoflink as it is a question from a company and I assume I'm not allowed to publish it

Comment: I don't know, I don't have enough details, but anyway, this is likely an offtopic question for this site

Comment: Wrong address maybe? Or a misspelling? Loading the page shows: The page you are looking for doesn't exist
You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved. If you think something is wrong feel free to contact support.